# Print content of element to console

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I have a feed that is outputting content dynamically to an element. I want to take the text from element A and output it to the console log.

Example:

```
<div class="elementa">ID5667</div>
```

Console Output:

ID : ID5667

I've tried a few things, but I'm either getting undefined or the full HTML of that element.

Comment: Please consider doing a little research before posting a question this basic. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript+element+content

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think below should work for you.

```
var result = document.getElementsByClassName("elementa")[0].innerHTML;

console.log(result);
```

For more reference : [getElementByClassName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the content of multiple classes you can do this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("className");

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript:

```
console.log('ID : ' + document.getElementsByClassName('elementa')[0].innerHTML);
```

jQuery:

```
console.log('ID : ' + $('.elementa').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

- The `.html()` method gives you the HTML contents ([see doc page](https://api.jquery.com/html/)). Use it as follows:

  ```
  console.log("ID: " + $("div.elementa").html())
  ```
- If you just want the text contents, use the `.text()` method ([see doc page](https://api.jquery.com/text/)):

  ```
  console.log("ID: " + $("div.elementa").text())
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to use jQuery as a tag indicates you can do that using [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
console.log($('.elementa').text());
```

It is also possible to use [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) but the behavior will be different if the HTML tags are present inside that tag. Compare two documentations.